# Changing the exe icon of VB6 project that uses a resource file

Tags: winapi, vb6, icons, resource-files

I need to change .exe icon for a VB6 project. I tried using the option generate .exe by selecting the form which loads first but this doesn't work as the previous exe icon comes from a resource file. I also tried adding the icon to the resource file, but VB 6 doesn't allow to add icons of more than 256 colours. Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 4):

Create a file named `YOURAPP.RC` containing the line

```
AAA        ICON        MOVEABLE        PRELOAD        YOURICON.ico
```

in the directory with the `YOURICON.ico` icon.

Then, compile to a resource file:

```
RC.EXE /v /r /fo YOURAPP.RES YOURAPP.RC
```

<sub>(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\Wizards\RC.EXE)</sub>

Finally, add the resulting `YOURAPP.RES` as a *Resource* to the VB6 project and recompile it.

Comment: When I try to compile to a resource file I get error "RC : fatal error RC1110 : could not open PFT_TOOLS.rc".

Isn't there any other way to add the icon to a existing resource file?

Comment: Are you running it from within the directory with the RC and ICO?

Comment: oh I wasn't running from the same directory. Your suggestion worked.  But the issue is there is already an resource file in the project and I need to add icon in it. Any solution for this?

Comment: You can use a tool like www.resedit.net to edit the existing *.RES

Comment: I tried that but the icon is not loaded when we open the resource file in vb6 resource editor.

Comment: It would not work with the built in editor, use an external one thats more functional

Answer (score -1):

Click on the Form your are working with then find the "Icon" entry in the properties page.

[image]

Then, go to project properties and in the second tab your icon will be set to your startup form's icon or whatever you choose.